# International keyboard crashing the app on the device

Tags: ios, xcode4.5

I have a problem when testing the app I wrote on the iPhone where I have set up an international keyboard.

The iPhone remembers the last input layout I used (i.e when I'm in messages and I'm using the hebrew keyboard, the next time I will use the keyboard in another app the hebrew layout will appear first) so when I'm running the app on the device and trying to input text into a textfield, the cursor appears but the keyboard doesn't, and any attempt to touch anywhere in the app causes a "Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1,address=0x14).

In addition, when the last layout I used is the english one, the app running perfectly even when I'm switching to the hebrew one.

I just noticed that it happens only with the "Name Phone Pad" keyboard, is there anyway to use this keyboard with international one?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it crash on the simulator?

Comment: No, the simulator doesn't show the international keyboard. I think it happens because I set all chars to be caps.

Comment: I think you just can't get to what is the exact reason of crash here. Please go to console & see what the log says. It might help you in better understanding what exactly is the problem. If you are seeing nothing in the log, Go to **Edit Scheme -> Arguments -> Environment Variables** and add a field there named **NSZombieEnabled** and set it's value to **YES**
. May be it can help in logging some info at the time the app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you have a delegate that's intercepting key strokes. I reccomend you either specify the first responder per textfield and see if that works or else localize the file for english (or whatever language) only.